# Plotly and Cufflinks in django

Tags: django, plotly

I am currently experimenting how to display graphs into my django templates. I have a little success by converting the plots into image then display it in a template. But this scheme is not suitable for interactive graphs like Plotly and Cufflinks.

How can I embed Plotly and Cufflinks into my django template so that my graph will be interactive?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`plotly.offline.plot` has an option `output_type='div'`, which makes the plot function return only a div containing the html of the plot.

```
plotly.offline.plot(data, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')
```

You can store this div in a variable, and pass it to the template.

Below is a minimal working example.
Note that we import the plotly.js in the header of the template file, and that we use the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter.

**view.py**

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np


class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "plots/index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['plot'] = examplePlot()
        return context


def examplePlot():
    # Makes a simple plotly plot, and returns html to be included in template.
    x = np.linspace(0, 12.56, 41)
    y = np.sin(x)
    y2 = np.sin(1.2*x)

    data = [
        go.Scatter(
            name = 'Sin(x)',
            x=x,
            y=y,
        ),

        go.Scatter(
            name = 'Sin(1.2x)',
            x=x,
            y=y2,
        ),
    ]

    layout = go.Layout(
        xaxis=dict(
            title='x'
        ),

        yaxis=dict(
            title='Value',
            hoverformat = '.2f'
        ),
    )

    fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
    plot_div = py.plot(fig, include_plotlyjs=False, output_type='div')

    return plot_div
```

**plots/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plotly test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{plot|safe}}
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's a screenshot of the result, which is interactive.
[image]